# C# How do I do I replace EventLogEntryType with a value from a comboBox?

Tags: c#

In the code below I want to replace EventLogEntryType.Warning with a value selected from a combo box, the combobox values are EventLogEntryType.Warning, EventLogEntryType.Information, EventLogEntryType.Error. The combo box would just show "Warning", "Information" and "Error". How can I do this?

Thanks

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog(); myLog.Source = "Test";             
int intEventID = int.Parse(txtEventID.Text);            
myLog.WriteEntry(txtDescription.Text, EventLogEntryType.Warning, intEventID);
```

Newbie

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that EventLogEntryType is an enum and that you don't need to localize, you can do this very easy.

In Form_Load

```
  combobox1.Items.Add(EventLogEntryType.Warning);
   combobox1.Items.Add(EventLogEntryType.Information);
   ...
```

and later

```
   myLog.WriteEntry(txtDescription.Text, (EventLogEntryType)combobox1.Selecteditem, intEventID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Enum.Parse` to translate the value from the combobox to your enum:

```
var sv = yourComboBox.SelectedValue;
var entryType = (EventLogEntryType) Enum.Parse(typeof(EventLogEntryType), sv);
```